# Build and construct a dataframe in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following code

```
for x in player_ids:
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    async def main():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            understat = Understat(session)
            player_shots = await understat.get_player_shots(
                x, 
                {"season": "2020", "situation": "OpenPlay"})
            df = pd.DataFrame(player_shots)
            return df

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
df=loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

For each iteration of the loop I would like to add the data to a dataframe. Would the way to do this be to create an empty dataframe and append?

Comment: Prefer append data to a list (or a dict). When all data are pulled, build your dataframe in once.